# Removing all abbreviations from Dragon NaturallySpeaking's dictionary

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there any way to remove all abbreviations from Dragon NaturallySpeaking's dictionary? I would like to get rid of all of them, and just add the few ones that I actually use.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the Vocabulary Editor and manually delete every word that you don't want. There is no property for "abbreviation" in the vocabulary so this cannot possibly done in an automated way.

You can speed up the process of selecting abbreviations by selecting "Words containing capital letters"  under "Display", because Abbreviations often contain Capital Letters (or punctuation, which is also an option).

Other than that there is nothing you can do.

[image: Screenshot of Dragon Vocabulary Editor]

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I feared :( I was hoping for some feature I had missed, or a way to edit the dictionary file directly, without going through Dragon NaturallySpeaking's GUI.

Comment: @Franck You're welcome. BTW, I notice that you ask a lot of Dragon questions here. I think you might be better served on a dedicated speech recognition forum (like KnowBrainer). You'd certainly get answers faster.

Comment: That's true, thanks for the suggestion, I've actually posted a couple of questions there (as well as in other DNS-specialized website). But I'm not a huge fan of forums, I find StackExchange to be much cleaner. I post to KB all questions that don't get an answer here, and if I get is a descent answer on KB I repost it here with a link to KB. I trust very few websites not to disappear overnight like speechcomputing did (http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=16687#92852).

Comment: Btw I also post some coding questions on [Stack Overflow])http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A395857+%5Bnaturallyspeaking%5D) ; I guess I'll put some unanswered ones on KB soon.